# How to create emailto hyperlink in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to create a hyper link in my windows phone XAML and code behind. Below is my code, but when I try this in my phone emulator, I get the below error:

```
"Can't send - Make sure you've set up an account and try again."
```

Will the below work on my actual phone?

XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton
Content="Click to Email"
Click="Hyperlink_Click"
/>
```

CodeBehind:

```
EmailComposeTask email = new EmailComposeTask();
email.Subject = "Subject";
email.To = "myemail@email.com";
email.Show();
```

Comment: [Another reason](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/11/phonehyperlinkbutton/) we all owe Jeff Wilcox a beer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) article, it seems that the `Emulator` doesn't work properly with the `Email Compose Task`. So better if you could test it in your device!